# my Android application runs proper on emulator but crashed on Motorola droid 2.2

Tags: android

I am getting below error in logcat.

```
> E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.net.mapapplication/com.net.mapapplication.MainPage}:       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2454)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4310)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)   
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at com.net.mapapplication.MainPage.onCreate(MainPage.java:23)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): ... 11 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): ... 21 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000f
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1710)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:548)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1850)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1799)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:282)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): ... 25 more
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:391)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1702)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3197): ... 29 more
```

My main XML file is as below:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon"
android:layout_width="35dp"
android:layout_marginTop="4px"
android:layout_marginRight="4px"
android:layout_marginLeft="4px">
</ImageView>
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/label"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:textColor="#999900"></TextView>
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The code for line at MainPage.java.23 is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
```

For above line layout for xml file splashscreen is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/paceuniversity">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Dude...Format your code.

Comment: You should explain a little more what you are doing... Just in case try cleaning up your project and recompiling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this :  `Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png from drawable resource ID #0x7f02000`. There is some resources error. Check whether this image exists and is being called correctly. You may also want to check all your XML files and resources.

Comment: at resource id - 0x7f020010, the image is different - paceuniversity.png, I never used any title_bar_shadow.9.png file in my app.

Comment: Look in your code and see where "title_bar_shadow" is used. In Eclipse you can do Ctrl+H and do a string search, find it and decide what to do, probably remove it and see if the error goes away. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Notice from your error log:

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: res/drawable-hdpi/title_bar_shadow.9.png E/AndroidRuntime( 3197)

If you have a file in the drawable-hdpi, you must have one in at least drawable (the default) and maybe drawable-mdpi (if you want it to work on devices that are not high density screens)

What is probably happening is that your emulator or phone are a different density so one finds the png in the drawable-hdpi directory but the other looks in drawable-mdpi and drawable directories and the file is not there?

Comment: I do not have any title_bar_shadow.9.png file in my application at all in any res folder. I found image in R.java file for resource ID #0x7f02000f as per error, but this file I have in all 3 folders - drawable-mdpi, ldpi and hdpi, still getting same error as above.